# I2C device not showing

Tags: raspbian, i2c

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 running Raspbian 3.18.11
I connected a DS18B20 sensor via i2c.

Problem is: it does not show up on `i2cdetect -y 1`

However, that data from the sensor is available at /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-xxx/w1_slave and seems to be correct (changing when touched).

`lsmod | grep` shows i2c_dev and i2c_bcm2708
`/boot/config.txt` has

> dtparam=i2c=on
>
> dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4

And blacklist.conf is empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DS18B20 is not an I2C device.

The DS18B20 is a so called 1-wire device and uses the Dallas 1-wire protocol.